# FileWriter only writes last line in a loop. Need it to write a log of all inputs

Tags: java

I have a JOptionPane that prompts the user to ask a question and receive a randomly generated answer. I"m trying to write a file that records all the questions and answers but FileWriter only records the last question & answer. Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;

public class Magic8Ball {

    public static void main(String [] args)throws Exception {

        final String QUIT = "quit";
        Random rand = new Random();
        int max = 7;
        int min = 0;
        int randomNum;

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("fortune.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        String[] answers = new String[8];

        String question = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter a question or " + QUIT + " to exit " );

        Create8Ball(answers);    

        while (!question.equals(QUIT)) {

            randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;   

          System.out.println(answers[randomNum]);

          pw.println("Question: " + question);
          pw.println("Fortune Response: " + answers[randomNum]);


           question = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter a question or " + QUIT + " to exit " );
            }

        pw.close();
        System.exit(0);

       }

       public static void Create8Ball(String answers[]) throws Exception
       {
         FileReader fr = new FileReader ("answers.txt");
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);

         String dog = null;
         int cat = 0;
         while ((dog = br.readLine()) != null)
          {
          answers[cat] = dog;
          cat++; 
           }
         //close the input file
         br.close();

       }

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append to the file:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("fortune.txt", true);
```

Comment: thank you! i took out BufferedWritter out and added pw.flush(); before pw.close(); seem to be doing the job.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want this constructor `FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)`. It will Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean indicating whether or not to append the data written.

Probably this one will work `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("fortune.txt",true);`